# jQuery('form').serialize(true) equivalent in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, serialization, request

I have tried searching this on the internet but could not find a relevant solution.

Also I am not sure if I would be able to explain this properly.

In short, I would like to know if there is an equivalent to `jQuery('form').serialize(true)` in C# to which I can pass a `HttpWebResponse`.

To explain it further

This code `jQuery('form').serialize(true)` is called on click of a page say `www.sample.com/xyz/`.

It is used as below (removed unnecessary code for simplicity)

```
function AjaxProductSelectorReport(targetElement) {
    var params = jQuery('form').serialize(true);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/handler/productselectorreporthandler.ashx",
        data: params,
        success: function (html) {
            //does something
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            //does something
        },
        error: function () {
            //does something
        }
    });
}
```

This handler "productselectorreporthandler" uses this as `context.Request["SomeKeyPresentInSerializedForm"]` within it. Please dont ask why because I frankly dont know. :)

I want to call this handler in some other page say `www.sample.com/abc/` but obviously the serialized form object passed should be that of `www.sample.com/xyz/`.

So I was thinking of programmatically calling `www.sample.com/xyz/` using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` but I am not sure how to pass this response to this handler.

This has become a huge post but I hope I have made my self clear.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to create an `HttpClient` to call the ashx

Comment: Yes I can do that but how to send the html string that got returned from the response as a NameValueCollection/Dictionary to this ashx?

Comment: You should describe the problem you're trying to solve rather than the problem you're having with the way you're trying to solve the problem.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.